# why is scipy.minimize ignoring my constraints?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a constrained optimization problem that I am trying to solve using scipy.optimize.minimize.

Basically, I am fitting one parameter, *f*,  to a system of ODEs with the constraint:
*f* >0 and

*f**1000< 500

I wrote a MWE below. In this simple case, it is obvious that 0<*f*<0.5, but in my real problem, it is not obvious the a-priori upper bound, hence the inequality contraint.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def myeqs(y,t,beta, gamma,N):
    dy0 = -(beta/N)*y[0]*y[1]
    dy1 = (beta/N)*y[0]*y[1] - gamma*y[1]
    dy2 = gamma*y[1]

    return [dy0,dy1,dy2]

def runModel(f, extraParams):
    [beta, gamma, N, initCond, time]= extraParams
    S0 = (1-f)*initCond[0]
    I0 = initCond[1]
    R0 = f*initCond[0]
    tspan = np.linspace(time[0], time[1], int(time[1] - time[0]))
    sol = odeint(myeqs, [S0,I0,R0], tspan, args=(beta, gamma, N))
    return sol

y0 = [1000, 1, 0]
extraParams = [0.5, 0.25, 1000, y0, [0,150]]


def computeSimple(f, extraParams):
   sol = runModel(f, extraParams)
   return np.abs((sol[-1,2] - sol[0,2]))


def c1(f):
    return f*1000.0 - 500.0


cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': c1})

#cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
 #  'fun': lambda x: x[0]*1000 - 500}, )

res = minimize(computeSimple, 0.2, args=(extraParams, ), method='SLSQP',       bounds=((0,1.5), ), constraints=cons)
print res.x

print c1(res.x)
```

If you run this, you will see that res.x is always the upper bound of bounds, regardless of the contraints...
Where is my mistake?
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you correct your indentation? Also, why are you defining `cons` twice?

Comment: The constraints in your code seem to be backwards from the constraints in your English.

Comment: @user2357112: You are exactly right! the constraints ARE backwards! that is the issue! can you please reply to my question so I can mark YOU as the one who answered it? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your constraint backward. This constraint:

```
def c1(f):
    return f*1000.0 - 500.0
```

is constraining `f` to be *at least* 0.5, instead of at most 0.5